# Git: progress bar on commit?

Tags: git, progress-bar

I hacked together a program that builds on git to provide a user-friendly [backup system.](https://bitbucket.org/arigo/arigo/raw/default/hack/gitbackup/gb_tkinter.py)  (So by construction, unlike the typical freeware alternatives on Windows, it gives full history and removes the risk of messing up by clicking "Backup" instead of "Restore" after your original files are gone.)  Despite this not being an obvious goal of git, it works great.  I use `git add -N . && git commit -a`.

But it would be helpful if the `git commit -a` could give feedback on its progress, because this command takes up to one hour to execute, having to compare or store many large new or modified binary files.  (There is no `git push` here; we directly do `git commit` into a repository that is on the backup device, outside the "working copy" of the original files, with `--git-dir`.)

The `--progress` option is documented in `git push` or `git clone`.  Is there no equivalent for `git commit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that `git add` has a `--verbose` option.  So far I did `git add -N` (fast, doesn't write the file content into the index) followed by `git commit -a`.  As it turns out, it is not significantly slower to do a slow `git add --verbose` followed by a regular `git commit`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there no equivalent for git commit?

No because the commit is a local operation which is supposed to be quite fast.
As opposed to fetch/push/pull/clone, which can involve network-wide communication, with multiple steps.

Comment: `git add --verbose` is really the answer to my question :-)